# When to use don't + pronoun

Tags: pronouns, negation, auxiliary-verbs, tag-questions

When have I to use "don't + pronoun"/"doesn't + pronoun"? I saw it a few times and I'm not sure how to use it.

An example could be:

> You're going to school, don't you?

Comment: The idiomatic way to say your example is "You **are** going to school, **aren't** you?" (I expanded the contraction to make the parallel between *are* and *aren't* clear, not because anybody would say it that distinctly)

Comment: This is called a **tag question**.

Answer (score 11):

In all the varieties of English that I am familiar with, a **tag question** on a sentence with an auxiliary (or a form of *be* even when it is a full verb) uses the auxiliary in the tag question, not *do*:

> You are coming, aren't you?
>
> He will win, won't he?
>
> I can finish it, can't I?
>
> He is, isn't he?

Only when there is no auxiliary, do we use a form of *do*:

> You like it, don't you?

I have heard some English speakers (from Pakistan, I think, but I'm not sure) using *isn't it* as an invariable tag question. I don't know of any who use *don't you/we/they* and *doesn't he/she* even where there is an auxiliary, but I would not be terribly surprised if there were a variety of English somewhere that did do this.

Comment: Aren't there some British varieties that use *innit?* pretty widely? Or am I just over-generalizing from stuff I've heard in movies & TV?

Comment: @ThePhoton - yes, I think so. That's a version of "isn't it", but you're right that some people (particularly younger ones) use the short version always.

Comment: In India, a lot of people say *isn't it?* irrespective of the sentence. It's actually a short version of saying *isn't it right what I said?*. *Drugs are bad. Isn't it..?*

Comment: @NVZ: Thank you. I thought it might be general in Indian English, but I'm not sure. However, I suspect that your explanation is a rationalisation: do you have any evidence that that is what is in people's mind when they say "Isn't it"? I think it's more likely to be a translation from the way tag questions are formed in another language.

Comment: *Isn't it?* comes naturally, although it's ungrammatical. I speak 4 Indian languages. So, yeah.

Comment: *Innit* is widely used as an invariable tag by young speakers in London and the surrounding areas.

Comment: @NVZ: i wouldn't call it ungrammatical, just non-standard.

Answer (score 6):

*Don't* is a contraction of "do not". *Doesn't* is a contraction of "does not". *Do* and *Does* are forms of the verb *to do*. Which one to use just comes down to conjugation:

I do. You do. He does. She does. We do. They do.

So

> You like apples, don't you?

but

> He likes cake, doesn't he?

Answer (score 4):

The two acceptable forms of this sentence are,

> "You're (You are) going to school, aren't you?" (are you not?)

and,

> "You go (You *do* go) to school, don't you?" (do you not?)

Comment: This gets to the right point.  I might go so far as to note that the second sentence is equivalent to, and could be said to imply, `You *do* go to school, don't you?`.  This stresses the relationship between `are` and `are you not`, and `do` and `do you not`

Comment: @J... Good point. I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't you* can also appear in negative imperatives:

> Don't you open that door!
>   Don't you touch that stove!

Normally, imperatives in English don't require any subject (addressee) pronoun.  The "you" is acting as an *intensifier* in these sentences.  Whoever is giving orders is angry, or will tolerate no disobedience.
It is similar to the effect of placing a swearword in the same position:

> Don't [bleep]ing open that door!

or appending the addressee's full name:

> Don't open that door, Jane Windslor Wexler!

Comment: How is this related to the question that was asked?

Comment: @ThePhoton It's talking about "don't + [pronoun]", which is exactly the question that was asked.  It explains one possible role of the pronoun in that formula, then shows non-pronouns filling the same role, to provide context for it.

Answer (score 1):

The tag question is opposite to the answer you want to suggest. So if you believe that someone goes to school and you want them to confirm it, you might say:

> You go to school, don't you?

but if you think (or suspect) they don't go to school and you want them to confirm that, you could say:

> You don't go to school, do you?

Answer (score 1):

1. You **can** dance, **can't** you?
2. You **will** dance, **won't** you?
3. You **have** danced, **haven't** you?
4. You **are** dancing, **aren't** you?

If you look at the sentences above you will see that they use the same auxiliary verb in the question as they do in the main sentence. So in the first sentence we see *can* and *can't*; in the second we see *will* and *won't*; in the third we see *have* and *haven't*; in the last wee see *are* and *aren't*. Notice that we can't use the main verb *dance* in the tag. We have to use an auxiliary verb.

Now look at the sentence below. Which auxiliary can you use here:

5. You dance, ___ you?

In sentence (5) we have a problem because there is no auxiliary verb in the main sentence. When we don't have an auxiliary verb in the main sentence we have to use a *dummy auxiliary*. The dummy auxiliary in English is the verb *DO*. When we don't have an auxiliary but we need one, we always use *DO*. It is like a spare tyre that we keep in the back of the car:

5. You dance, **don't** you?